# / in vi Search and replace?

Tags: vim, text, replace

in vi, search and replace, how do you escape a '/' (forward slash) so that it is correct. Say in a path.

like: /Users/tom/documents/pdfs/

```
:%s//Users/tom/documents/pdfs//<new text>/g  --FAILS (obviously)

:%s/\/Users/tom/documents/pdfs\//<new text>/g -- FAILS with a trailing error

:%s/'/Users/tom/documents/pdfs/'/<new text>/g -- FAILS with a trailing error
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM find/search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465156/how-does-one-escape-backslashes-and-forward-slashes-in-vim-find-search)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slashes internally, too.

```
:%s/\/Users\/tom\/documents\/pdfs\//<new text>/g
```

Answer (score 136):

Alternatively you can do `:%s,foo/bar/baz,foo/bar/boz,g` - I almost *never* use slashes because of the escaping confusion.

Comment: Dude, I didn't know about that!  I'm guessing you could use any character to delimit the fields then?

Comment: Yeah I believe so, I just got accustomed to commas.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: Nice tip! You can also save yourself the repetition with the `n` flag, which does the search without the replace. e.g. `:%s,foo/bar/baz,,gn`

Comment: Didn't know that it will work commas. I got accustomed to `%s:old/old:/old/new:g`

Comment: when I search "/$$$", it doesn't find something like "$$$texthere" unless I type "/$$$texthere". Does it have something to do with special characters and spaces?

Comment: I tried this on solaris 86-64 in vi and it didn't work. what am i doing wrong? %s,C:/app/my.home/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1,$MY_HOME,g tried without the $ and that didn't work either.

Comment: In :%s,foo/bar/baz,foo/bar/boz,g do the slashes still need escaping internally?

Answer (score 19):

As Sarah suggested, you need to escape ALL forward slashes.

You could instead use another character besides forward-slash as the delimiter.  This is handy if your search string has a lot of slashes in it.

```
:%s#/Users/tom/documents/pdfs/#<new test>#g
```

This works perfectly in vim.  I'm not 100% sure about vanilla vi.

Comment: I can't think of how you'd even get at vi these days.  I was thinking most major Linux distros just redirect 'vi' to vim with lots of features turned off.

Comment: Because linux isn't the only os :)

Many of the BSDs ship with vanilla vi or nvi

Most of the commercial unix systems do as well.  I remember (unhappily) the days of having to compile vim on IRIX because I couldn't live with vanilla vi.

Comment: Not too long ago Debian linked vi to nvi, as did NetBSD, FreeBSD, and OpenBSD. Some also shipped with vim-as-vim.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is several years old, but for others who may land upon this one searching for an easier solution, in 2014, you can substitute the "/" delimiter for something else like "!", as long as you do it in front, middle, and back, like this:

```
:%s!foo/bar/baz!foo/bar/boz!g
```

Very simiar to Meder's answer ... But, I find that the exclamation is a lot easier to view as a separator. And I just wanted to confirm that this method still works in the current version of VIM, which I am using in Mac OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `?` to search

In case of searching pattern in a register, and the pattern contains a '/' character, you can simply use `?` command instead of `/` command from normal mode to start pattern matching. In such case, no more escape required for '/' char. (however you need to escape '?' char now)

`?` will search in the opposite direction of `/`, so if you don't mind the search direction, and your search pattern doesn't contains '?' char.

In addition, check the `escape()` script if you want more.

Comment: Genius! I was just searching (with `/`) and not replacing, so I didn't have a delimiter to change.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses backslash for directories and Linux uses forward slash for directories. Vim is a text editor that works for operating-systems. Since both os have different directory path interpretation *regarding how slashes are used,* Vim must then need a way to interpret Windows twisted method.

### LINUXFORWARD vs. WINDOWSBACK (DIRECTORY SLASHES)

- The slashes are literally reversed in Windows and easily stated for Linux

  - Windows:
  - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\`
  - Linux:
  - `/usr/bin`

### SOLUTION

> I'm only able to state the struggle for Vim's Find & Replace on Windows as i'm not on a Linux pc.

- Fix is to double backslash

  - GOOD:
  - `:%s/c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft OneDrive\\/annoyancereplaced/g`
  - BAD:
  - `:%s/c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\/unabletoreplaceannoyance/g`

NOTE

- If working with **network paths** where Windows uses two slashes `\\` then that means for every backslash there needs to be another backslash as it's always kept even

  - e.g. network path: `\\Foo\Bar\`
  - `%s/C:\\Program Files (x86)\\foo\\bar/\\\\Foo\\Bar\\`
  - notice the `\\\\`