# How does one escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM find/search?

Tags: regex, vim

For instance, if I wanted to a find and replace with strings containing backward or forward slashes, how would this be accomplished in vim?

Examples
Find & Replace is: `:%s/foo/bar/g`

what if I wanted to find all occurrences of `<dog/>` and replace it with `<cat\>`

Comment: Not strictly an answer, but you should probably read :help magic

Comment: +1 Tom, generally the most sane solution when working with a more than trivial regex.

Comment: @Tom @Randy however... the `vi --help` on my server does NOT provide explanation of escaping special characters... which is why people come to stackoverflow to begin with...

Comment: @aequalsb `:help magic` is something you type *inside* vim. It's not a command-line argument to vim.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Same way you escape characters most anywhere else in linuxy programs, with a backslash:

```
:%s/<dog\/>/<cat\\>
```

But note that you can select a different delimiter instead:

```
:%s@<doc/>@<cat\\>@
```

This saves you all typing all those time-consuming, confusing backslashes in patterns with a ton of slashes.

From the [documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_delimiters_for_the_replace_command):

> Instead of the `/` which surrounds the pattern and replacement string, you
>   can use any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric character,
>   `\`, `"` or `|`.  This is useful if you want to include a `/` in the search
>   pattern or replacement string.

Comment: So it will automatically figure out your chosen delimiter?

Comment: Yes. The character after the `s` is taken to be the delimiter. I can't figure out where I've found a list in the documentation, but I'm pretty sure at least `/:;*%@#` are valid.

Comment: This comes in handy when replacing \ into / in a file with lots of Windows-style paths.  Thanks.

Comment: To get to that message in the documentation, use: h e146

Comment: Had no idea you could change the delimiter! That's huge - thanks.

Comment: Thanks for note for delimiter, that kind of hints we need here :)

Answer (score 27):

```
%s:<dog/>:<cat>
```

You can replace the / delimiters if they become annoying for certain patterns.

Comment: +1 for `:` delimiter. I didnt know you could use that. I always used `@` in times of 'escape-mess'

Comment: @JeffreyJose Whatever character follows the `:s` is defined to be the delimiter character. You can use most non-alphanumeric characters (but not ``\``, `"` or `|`).
([source](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Alternate_delimiters_for_the_replace_command))

Answer (score 8):

Quote them with a backslash.  Also, it often helps to use another delimiter besides slash.

```
 :%s#<dog/>#<cat\\>#
```

or if you have to use slash as the substitute command delimiter

```
 :%s/<dog\/>/<cat\\>/
```

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for something similar, to search for register values containing the `/` character (to record a macro). The solution was to search using the `?` token instead of the `/`.

Comment: Note that `?` will do a backward search, and is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
:%s/<dog\/>/<cat\\>/g
```

Answer (score -1):

backslash slash backslash star

```
/(<- the prompt)\/\*
```

so after you type it looks like

```
/\/\*
```

Comment: How is this answer different from those that have been on the site for close to six years?