# Replace backward slash '\' with forward slash '/' in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I have some scripts(linux) which are generating the o/p with respect to Windows. I expect it to be `/home/manty/...` it generates `\home\manty\...` It is very annoying when I try to change one by one all the time. So just for this purpose, I am leaving vim and going to `gedit` to perform "find and replace". How can I do it in vim?

I tried with following :

```
:%s/\\/\/
```

It changed only in the two places. I tried several other combinations as well nothing is working out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include forward slash in vi search & replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823616/how-to-include-forward-slash-in-vi-search-replace)

Comment: Or: [How does one escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM find/search?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2465156/55075)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ah. I missed the `g` thing.

```
:%s/\\/\//g
```

This command does the trick. `g` stands for global and will make the change globally (complete file).

Also, you can add an extra option of `c` if you want to monitor each change. If you want to use `c` option the command would be `:%s/\\/\//gc` and then select `y` or `n` for each change.

I will wait for better answers from vim geeks. I am sure there must be a better way.

Comment: If you use `g` you can avoid `%`: `:s/\\/\//g` makes it.

Comment: Thank you. Ok so then at first place only %s why didnt it work?

Comment: with out %, it is replacing only for one line. I wanted throught the file

Comment: It may depend on your `vi` version perhaps? In http://www.linfo.org/vi/search.html they suggest it, so I was also confused because my attempts only replaced once as well.

Comment: By using a different separator (e.g. `#`), you can avoid the escaping of the forward slash: `:%s#\\#/#g`

Answer (score 9):

You can use another delimiter like this:

```
 :%s,\\,/,g
```

Comment: What you posted here is identical to `:%s@,/@g`. Backslash escapes *any* separator, there is no way to omit two backslashes.

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat, but with `:%s,//,,g` to remove double Forwardslashes.