# How to match "\n" in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, newline

In my code I have regular expressions containing the string `\n` and
I want to replace them with `[\r\n]+`
How should I escape the `s///g` command to do that?
Searching for `\n` matches newlines within the code, so I guess the problem is I am not escaping the character properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM find/search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2465156/1255289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right, here is how you can escape both the search and the replacement strings:

```
s/\\n/[\\r\\n]+/g
```