# Trying to replace " to \" in vi terminal

Tags: linux, vi

Assume i have a text file have a text like this "hello world" Now i want to replace the double quotes (") with slash with double quotes (\") i have used `:%s/"/\"/g` to replace, but it is not worked

Comment: escape the backslash like this `:%s/"/\\"/g`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww from the link you posted "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

vi and vim are valid tags on stack overflow and these kinds of questions are therefore also valid.

If your problem is that the question is a duplicate or a question that could be googled easily, then raise that concern.

Comment: Thanks Stun. No, I selected the correct reason based on my understanding of the site's rules. How to operate your favorite text editor falls out of bounds because there's nothing unique to software development. Maybe you were thinking of an example like running make from your IDE? I would agree with you for an example like that because it touches a Makefile which is commonly found when developing software.

Comment: Please take it to meta, the sites rules also say comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to find or replace a backslash `\` you need to let vim know that you are not actually trying to escape the character to the right of that backslash. The way you do that is to escape the backslash with **another** backslash, like this `\\` so that the first backslash escapes the backslash to the right of it.

This gives you

```
:%s/"/\\"/g
```

A great place to learn about this is
http://vimregex.com/

Comment: Lo and behold... Already asked and answered: [vim regex not need \ to escape](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23419/56041), [How does one escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2465156/608639), etc. You really should move to close these questions.

Comment: @jww please feel free to move to close the question.

Comment: Ummmmmmmmm, I did.

Comment: @jww Congratulations then?