# How to include forward slash in vi search & replace

Tags: search, vim, replace, vi

I have a file that contains the string `usrbin`. I want to search for `usrbin` and replace it with `/usr/bin/`.

I tried `:%s/usrbin/usr/bin/g`, but it's showing error `E488: Trailing characters`.

How do I include a forward slash in a search and replace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM find/search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465156/how-does-one-escape-backslashes-and-forward-slashes-in-vim-find-search)

Comment: possible duplicate of [/ in vi Search and replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684628/in-vi-search-and-replace)

Answer (score 145):

Here are two ways:

- escape the `/` which is the default substitute separator: `:s/usrbin/\/usr\/bin`
- use another substitute separator, e.g., using the hash `#` character: `:s#usrbin#/usr/bin`. Note that there are characters that you can't use as a separator: `"`, `\`, `|`

You can review this in the help subsystem using `:h pattern-delimiter`

Comment: thanks @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功! I added edits. Comment if you can think of any other characters that can't be used as alternate delimiters

Comment: great answer, this is ideal if you want to replace a long URL value because escaping all those forward slashes is no fun at all

Comment: There are problems with | (pipe) as the delimiter when replacing backslashes such as "PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Temp;C:\Users" via :s|\\|/|g but I never figured out why so I just use # as a delimiter instead

Comment: FYI, the relevant vim help on this topic is `:h pattern-delimiter`.

Comment: When I try ```:h pattern-delimiter``` I get the error ```E149: Sorry, no help for pattern-delimiter```

Comment: @nikost check your vim install, or check on another vim installation. Sounds like your vim install doesn't have all a complete installation. What do you see when you just type `:h`?

Comment: I see this as the first line when I type ```:h``` ```help.txt*      For Vim version 8.1.  Last change: 2019 Jul 21```. I will try updating, I would think this help is older than 2019