# Searching for \[ in VIM

Tags: search, vim, tex

I have a TeX file that contains lines like

```
\[ De = 0 \]
```

Now my boss wants equation numbers so I want them to be like

```
\begin{equation}De = 0\end{equation}
```

I tried the following command by escaping the backslash with a backslash.

```
:%s@\\[@\\begin{equation}@gc
```

I think this should work but I am getting pattern not found error.
I have looked at

[How to include forward slash in vi search & replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823616/how-to-include-forward-slash-in-vi-search-replace)

and

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Can somebody tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that worked for you. That way other people that have the same question will see that it was already answered on first sight.

Answer (score 6):

You have to escape both characters: `:%s_\\\[ _\\begin{equation}_g`.

EDIT: Since you also asked for an explanation:

Why escape the `\`?

Vim supports different pattern matching styles (*see `:help /magic`*), but escape characters have to be escaped in all of them.

Why escape the `[`?

`[]` in patterns are used as collections. Thus you have to escape the `[` to match it literally.