# How to search and replace in Vim/Linux if our searching/replacing pattern includes multiple forward slashes?

Tags: linux, vim, solaris, putty

I have 100K rows file and every row contain date 12/13/2019. I want to replace that date with 12/20/2019. But when I am entering the command like :%s/12/13/2019/12/20/2019/g. It gives an error that couldn't find pattern.
Format for date is (MM/DD/YYYY)

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or [vim.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: use backslashes and be careful of course on your REGEXP .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include forward slash in vi search & replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823616/how-to-include-forward-slash-in-vi-search-replace)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+search+slash

Comment: @phd I'm not sure that's a full duplicate.  This question includes a `solaris` tag, and the behavior of current versions of `vim` and/or `vi` may not be applicable to the `vi` likely found on older Solaris releases.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm sure it's a full dup. Escaping slash with a backslash or using a different search character works in any `vi` clone in any OS.

Answer (score 1):

A substitution is made of several parts:

```
:<range>s/<search>/<replace>/<flags>
```

Between those parts, you have `/` as default separator. Since `/` separates the `<search>` part from the `<replace>` part, any `/` in your search pattern is going to be interpreted as a separator, leading to undesirable results.

One solution is to escape your slashes with an anti-slash:

```
:%s/12\/13\/2019/12\/20\/2019/g
```

Another one (my favourite) is to use an alternative separator:

```
:%s@12/13/2019@12/20/2019@g
```

Reference:

```
:help :s
:help pattern-delimiter
```